# ASUS Precision Touchpad not listed/found in ubuntu. ASUS TUF FX504GE-EN224T

Tags: kernel, touchpad, asus

This is a new laptop version from ASUS. I have somehow installed ubuntu on it after referring to various posts. But still, I am not able to configure the touchpad. There are solutions proposed that upgrading the kernel to 4.19.1+ fixes the problem. I have tried 4.19.1, 4.19.2, 4.19.3, 4.19.4, 4.19.5, 4.19.6 but still the problem persists.

The output of `xinput list` is

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus Wireless Radio Control               id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam: USB2.0 HD           id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

On Windows system, the touchpad is listed as `ASUS Precision Touchpad`

The output of `cat /proc/bus/input/devices` is

```
I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0003 Version=0000
N: Name="Sleep Button"
P: Phys=PNP0C0E/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input0
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event0 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=4000 0 0

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0001 Version=0000
N: Name="Power Button"
P: Phys=PNP0C0C/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input1
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event1 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=10000000000000 0

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0005 Version=0000
N: Name="Lid Switch"
P: Phys=PNP0C0D/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0D:00/input/input2
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event2 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=1

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0001 Version=0000
N: Name="Power Button"
P: Phys=LNXPWRBN/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input3
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event3 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=10000000000000 0

I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0001 Product=0001 Version=ab83
N: Name="AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio0/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event4 leds 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=120013
B: KEY=402000000 3803078f800d001 feffffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe
B: MSC=10
B: LED=7

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0006 Version=0000
N: Name="Video Bus"
P: Phys=LNXVIDEO/video/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input5
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event5 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=3e000b00000000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0006 Version=0000
N: Name="Video Bus"
P: Phys=LNXVIDEO/video/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:13/LNXVIDEO:01/input/input6
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event6 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=3e000b00000000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=1043 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="Asus Wireless Radio Control"
P: Phys=asus-wireless/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/ATK4002:00/input/input11
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=rfkill kbd event11 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=80000000000000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=13d3 Product=5666 Version=0322
N: Name="USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam: USB2.0 HD"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-7/button
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/input/input12
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event12 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=100000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="Asus WMI hotkeys"
P: Phys=asus-nb-wmi/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/asus-nb-wmi/input/input13
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=rfkill kbd event13 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=100013
B: KEY=1000000080000 0 800000000000 0 0 a1606f00900000 8200027800701000 e000000000000 0
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input14
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event14 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=4

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input15
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event15 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input16
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event16 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input17
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event17 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input18
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event18 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=10"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input19
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event19 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140
```

In both the cases the touchpad is not recognised at the kernel level.

Can I assume safely that there is no support for this trackpad as of now. Or is there any other mechanism through which I can debug this?

PS: External mouse works just fine. It works good on windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you try kernel 4.19.11? I am using FX504GE too. Just run these command to update your kernel:

```
# fix touchpad kernel
mkdir /tmp/install
cd /tmp/install
wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.19.11/linux-headers-4.19.11-041911_4.19.11-041911.201812191931_all.deb
wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.19.11/linux-headers-4.19.11-041911-generic_4.19.11-041911.201812191931_amd64.deb
wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.19.11/linux-image-unsigned-4.19.11-041911-generic_4.19.11-041911.201812191931_amd64.deb
wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.19.11/linux-modules-4.19.11-041911-generic_4.19.11-041911.201812191931_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

The only not solved bug is when there is 5 touch in your touchpad, it will freeze. To solve this problem I run this script as root:

```
SUSPEND_MODULES="i2c_hid"

for mod in $SUSPEND_MODULES; do
    rmmod $mod
    modprobe $mod
done
```

I hope this will help you :D

Comment: Hey Prakash,

Tried upgrading it to 4.19.11, 4.19.13, 4.20. Nothing works. The problem is my hardware is not getting detected. Can you post the output of `xinput list`

Comment: Hi @JayChakra please look at this gist https://gist.github.com/prakashdivyy/73dea0317fb78b7c2b7f424cb306b313

Comment: Thanks. In your gist it is specifically showing the `elantech touchpad` which was not in my case.  After careful observation I noticed that I was running `Ubuntu 18.04.1 minimal install` So, I tried and tested it on the regular flavour of Ubuntu. It works out of box. Marking it as fixed. :)

Comment: Hi, I am having same problem you've had except that I am not using ubuntu.
I understand that the issue has been resolved for you but do you mind sharing output from `lsmod` command to figure out what modules I am missing?